# Server install of kvm and openstack without broadband

Tags: installation, server, kvm-virtualization, openstack

I've always installed Ubuntu desktop (many versions and flavors) with a decent internet connection, but now I find myself preparing for my first-ever server install (13.04 chosen for the need of Grizzly), in a place without broadband. I therefore wish to prepare for installing everything from media, which I would download before I wander off to the Boonies.

How can I download all the files I would need for a complete Open Stack install, on a single machine, before I leave the blue blanket of my broadband connection?

Once downloaded and a basic install performed, would I install additional packages needed by apt after revising `/etc/apt/sources.lst` to point to where the Big Pile o' Files be, or would I manually install each with dpkg, or, on the Gripping Hand, do it in a way I do not yet recognize?

Comment: You want to use openstack, or what kind of packages you plan to use?

Comment: Yes, Openstack Grizzly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just install the packages I wanted before moving in that circumstance. This might be useful if you can download packages elsewhere, save them to a flash drive, then copy to your Big Pile o' Files. 

Lucky for you, someone has already figured it out: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Offline/Repository/ 

And another thread for reference:
[How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Comment: Worked like a champ. Collecting OpenStack stuph now.

Comment: Happy to help.  Please mark the question as answered.  Which approach did you use?

Comment: http://www.howtoforge.com/local_debian_ubuntu_mirror